# Regex in python to get certain PLSQL statement

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, extract, ddl

i have this code and need a regex to get the code from pl sql to get the lines with the constraint and check

CREATE TABLE

```
 "OWB_RUN"."WITHOUT_RESCHEDULING_OFFER"
   (    "RESCHEDULING_OFFER_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "OFFER_DAY" DATE,
    "F_OFFER_MADE" NUMBER(1,0),
    "F_ACCEPTED" NUMBER(1,0),
    "CIF" VARCHAR2(8),
     CONSTRAINT "FS_WITHOUT_RESCHED_OFFERS_N1" CHECK (cif IS NOT NULL
) ENABLE,
     CONSTRAINT "FS_WITHOUT_RESCHED_OFFERS_N2" CHECK (offer_day IS NOT NULL
) ENABLE,
     CONSTRAINT "FS_WITHOUT_RESCHED_OFFERS_N3" CHECK (f_accepted IS NOT NULL
) ENABLE,
     CONSTRAINT "FS_WITHOUT_RESCHED_OFFERS_C1" CHECK (f_accepted IN (0,1,2)
) ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 1048576 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "APPL_WORK_TBL"
  PARALLEL
```

I want an output like this:

```
['CONSTRAINT "FS_WITHOUT_RESCHED_OFFERS_N1" CHECK (cif IS NOT NULL)',
 'CONSTRAINT "FS_WITHOUT_RESCHED_OFFERS_N2" CHECK (offer_day IS NOT NULL)',
 'CONSTRAINT "FS_WITHOUT_RESCHED_OFFERS_N3" CHECK (f_accepted IS NOT NULL)',
 'CONSTRAINT "FS_WITHOUT_RESCHED_OFFERS_C1" CHECK (f_accepted IN (0,1,2))']
```

Comment: Just to comment on your constraints - a check constraint with an `is not null` condition is not quite the same thing as a `not null` constraint. Database tools will still list the column as nullable, and there are scenarios where the optimiser can use the knowledge that a column is mandatory to make a more efficient execution plan, but it can only get this information from actual `not null` constraints, not from arbitrary check constraints. Therefore, `constraint fs_without_resched_offers_n1 not null` is preferable to `constraint fs_without_resched_offers_n1 check(gif_is_not_null)`.

Comment: Also, PL/SQL is a programming language. Table definitions are not PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `text` the variable that stores the input, you can try:

```
import re

out = re.findall(r'CONSTRAINT "[^"]+" CHECK \([^)]+\)+',
                 ''.join(map(str.strip, text.splitlines())))
```

Output:

```
['CONSTRAINT "FS_WITHOUT_RESCHED_OFFERS_N1" CHECK (cif IS NOT NULL)',
 'CONSTRAINT "FS_WITHOUT_RESCHED_OFFERS_N2" CHECK (offer_day IS NOT NULL)',
 'CONSTRAINT "FS_WITHOUT_RESCHED_OFFERS_N3" CHECK (f_accepted IS NOT NULL)',
 'CONSTRAINT "FS_WITHOUT_RESCHED_OFFERS_C1" CHECK (f_accepted IN (0,1,2))']
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will do the trick :

```py
import re

sql_script = """
 "OWB_RUN"."WITHOUT_RESCHEDULING_OFFER"
...
"""

constraint_pattern = r'CONSTRAINT\s+"[\w_]+"(?:\s+CHECK\s+\([^\)]+\))'
matches = re.findall(constraint_pattern, sql_script, re.IGNORECASE)
print(matches)
```

You can find an explanation of this regex here : https://regexr.com/7cm9j